# Analog versus digital (I2S) audio transmission over 1-2m

Tags: transmission-line, digital-communications, microphone

I need to get a microphone signal to a microprocessor about 1-2m away via cable and I need it to be digitized at some point in this chain. I'm looking for a solution that draws something on the order of ~10mW not including the microphone and microcontroller.

I'm comparing the strategy of using a digital MEMS microphone with I2S output versus using an analog MEMS microphone and digitizing (24bit, Fs=44kHz) on the board with the microprocessor. Digital MEMS are beautifully simple (eliminating ADC complexity) and impressively power efficient compared to traditional approaches so they are tempting.

I2S won't travel 1-2m. LVDS drivers may be able to extend range over a well designed cable, but drivers all seem to blow the power budget. They support bitrates of ~0.5 to 2.5Gbps which is way beyond my needs (1.4Mbps). Is there no standard which supports medium ranges and bit rates without such high power dissipation? Would designing a custom driver be a silly endeavor?

Or is analog really still the best bet here?

Answer (score 3):

MEMS mics also (more frequently) use PDM for digital communications.  PDM (Pulse Density Modulation) is essentially the output of the analog front end of a sigma-delta DAC.  Many CODECs will accept that input directly, and it will probably be lower power than I2S.

By doing this, instead of pushing the whole ADC to the mic, you're just pushing the (trickier) analog portion, and doing most of the digital work at the CODEC.  It may be that DSP oriented uPs are starting to accept PDM as well.

Comment: Shouldn't this be sensitive to the same kinds of distortion over longer cables that I2Sc is (time shift between generated clock and returned data plus reflections and rise time issues from cable capacitance)?

Comment: @davegravy PDM runs in the single-digit MHz clock range, similar to I2S.  However, the synchronization is rather less complex, particularly as the clock is sourced and the data sampled at the codec end of the cable, which offers a bit of forgiveness in any setup and hold context.  I haven't seen a spec for max length, but I've run them over 2m of loose wires as part of a demo, and had no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you need to match the cable impedance to the circuit design to improve signal integrity.

- You extend the range of I2C for signals <= 20 MHz/meter by careful design.
- If using an Rx interface with hystereis, optimize the margin for Rx swing with minimal ringing and overshoot by damping the signal with the optimum series R and possibly with an active load biased to Vdd/2.
- perfect matched impedance also reduces the swing by 50% which noise margin with threshold offsets,

  - so often a slightly lower source R is added (22 to 51) and no load except Cin pF, is used as long as no parasitic ESL and C is added in the layout. But this is not enough for some cables.
  - these parasitics (ESL,C) deteriorate signal quality with rise times < 1/2 of the cable propagation delay due to mismatched impedances.
  - most (but not all) plastic insulated cable travels around 2/3 c velocity or 2e8 m/s or ~ 5 ns /m and rise times is expected << 10 ns for a 2m cable.  The driver is also single-ended rather than differential, so the impedances are not  balanced. This is what limits I2C cable length in typical designs. For ethernet, this is signficantly improved with a hybrid balun which operate at much higher frequency.

STP cables are not all the same

[image]

- The [3m cable above](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/22045O/3mtm-round-shielded-jktd-disc-wire-cable-3750-series-ts0072.pdf)  use DUAL shielded multi-twisted pair cables which are rated at  35 db average shielding with multiple twisted pairs and higher Dk plastic, so 56% c is lower than 2/3 c

[image]
The above [cable from IOaudio](https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/8176a5_7b71e9aa40544c499f385685eae0e9ba.pdf) is 54pF/m vs 59.4 pF/m for the 3M cable

- Decoupling caps also add ESL from traces about 1nH/mm which adds signal degradation from ringing with the CMOS capacitance , so they must be placed directly next to IC pins or across pwr/gnd plane nearby.
- a CM choke raises and balances the single ended twisted pair to improve CMRR of interference and make them more balanced . [These can be low cost $0.25 solutions raising the Zcm to hundreds of ohms while having a DCR around 1 ohm for this application.](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Laird%20Technologies/EMI_Filtering_and_RF_Inductors.pdf)
- This device use 1.7 to 3.6V max CMOS technology which is called low voltage LV CMOS and also lower resistance than 74HCxx logic at the same Vdd. It also rises with lower Vgs=Vdd  on the CMOS FETs.
- Lower voltage also reduces load current for each clock+data transition.

After you define the actual risetimes, bit rates and cable length, then you can start with design specs for something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO7hHe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Transmission line simulation at 5MHz.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBMB0CsCmBaAjBAzHAnJtbkA581YA2SIzEkWCWa2pZZAKACVryRlNIQAWSlx5co9MOPHho%20OmGmypsZgCcO%20Ib1h8%20G8PwDszAOYgSfCJFKnzUQnrDMA7tYtWSYdZaoOAxiH0k6ty8AZ5WFoy8yNBo%20GBo%20vqE2MiwcYlS4iwm%20mhUXv55tuoQDs74gsEg%20HxBwmXVtVBWoc3eKv6BujV1vBAszq0FufnhHe69Lrr9zMj6yFNVI9NQ0GAIiEHE1uAdFVRMvPtcAXqo4mzVlchHgnH2-P3Q%20g9ySqrH5OqfkDr9Ek4QJhtN1KvVmH4JrooQUIigotBMEx8PN5nhKJZIH01mABkCQQUem1ds4tDoqrBTlUHAAPUy4EC4BZxdBoHTk9kAWwAOgBnSBvPkAO15fN5ABsAJYAE3gyj5PgA9kKAC7KRXi8XwaV8gBazHF1Cpwih1K4SHUiDk4m0sFIfHcCSYmBkJWYApeZn6JpsyBBOhVNPdYBeyyWRT97JArCDHvx5OEwI5UcVAFcVcxzGguOsDjcuOR%20u57AB9PglsBl-AkfQlmCwCvQZB1kssLM5qxVG73X6lKDN8uV5Bodb4OtN9whsC-JK5SjN61ZFvNgAqQfbqCsBW76DAfygkDLFdbI7S47i2lSRGHaB4AsPi9xy8z8Q7VDQAoL91i%208gaCPQ6WHwtYwHEqB%20u4%20g0NoWKNhIzaHiwhphsIrRmsgFqZFkw6BLesA4GASLcDWux%20EmujkbC5ooAs0SxNOrqoLEkBIvhWEsHSDq0X%20phkAWVAcgYfKOAAhqKvIAFapryKp8gAsgAonJ4nSsokoAG5ynqfLwDJkqciJKrwMwnFsdg-gOjmvCCagwoABJ8iJQo6vyAAOABifJSTJfIAGaKvKvKuSJyhiZKKqSj4fKcoqsriryAA0jnOXyADCkpCnyMYmaY%20ALHwTAFjxBVRn6IBCoqjjRWmvLwI4AAW8DwOKfIqo1rWOIqfLIHyir1TyvKsAA5OJKpdby5y9f14lOS5Pj1U5RjwAqIkAEZany%20mudqTk%20PASW8kqIoylpEqKiJLmsMwip6Puw6jqscT4Fi6w4OQlLTtmj4LBAOiQD9B56DxEBKpyq0ZdqzCxFwtE5hYkg%20GtG28rqfIACKSr5vl8tyACO3XiK140CmAU2cryzBAA)  [Make an ugly signal look better.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBMB0CsCmBaAjBAzHAnJtbkA581YA2SIzEkWCWa2pZZAKACVryRlNIQAWSlx5co9MOPHho%20OmGmypsZgCcO%20Ib1h8%20G8PwDszAOYgSfCJFKnzUQnrDMA7tYtWSYdZaoOAxiH0k6ty8AZ5WFoy8yNBo%20GBo%20vqE2MiwcYlS4iwm%20mhUXv55tuoQDs74gsEg%20HxBwmXVtVBWoc3eKv6BujV1vBAszq0FufnhHe69Lrr9zMj6yFNVI9NQ0GAIiEHE1uAdFVRMvPtcAXqo4mzVlchHgnH2-P3Q%20g9ySqrH5OqfkDr9Ek4QJhtN1KvVmH4JrooQUIigotBMEx8PN5nhKJZIH01mABkCQQUem1ds4tDoqrBTlUHAAPUy4EC4BZxdBoHTk9kAWwAOgBnSBvPkAO15fN5ABsAJYAE3gyj5PgA9kKAC7KRXi8XwaV8gBazHF1Cpwih1K4SHUiDk4m0sFIfHcCSYmBkJWYApeZn6JpsyBBOhVNPdYBeyyWRT97JArCDHvx5OEwI5UcVAFcVcxzGguOsDjcuOR%20u57AB9PglsBl-AkfQlmCwCvQZB1kssLM5qxVG73X6lKDN8uV5Bodb4OtN9whsC-JK5SjN61ZFvNgAqQfbqCsBW76DAfygkDLFdbI7S47i2lSRGHaB4AsPi9xy8z8Q7VDQAoL91i%208gaCPQ6WHwtYwHEqB%20u4%20g0NoWKNhIzaHiwhphsIrRmsgFqZFkw6BLesA4GASLcDWux%20EmujkbC5ooAs0SxNOrqoLEkBIvhWEsHSDq0X%20phkAWVAcgYfKOAAhqKvIAFapryKp8gAsgAonJ4nSsokoAG5ynqfLwDJkqciJKrwMwnFsdg-gOjmvCCagwoABJ8iJQo6vyAAOABifJSTJfIAGaKvKvKuSJyhiZKKqSj4fKcoqsriryAA0jnOXyADCkpCnyMYmaY%20ALHwTAFjxBVRn6IBCoqjjRWmvLwI4AAW8DwOKfIqo1rWOIqfLIHyir1TyvKsAA5OJKpdby5y9f14lOS5Pj1U5RjwAqIkAEZany%20mudqTk%20PASW8kqIoylpEqKiJLmsMwip6Puw6jqscT4Fi6w4OQlLTtmj4LBAOiQD9B56DxEBKpyq0ZdqzCxFwtE5hYkg%20GtG28rqfIACKSr5vl8tyACO3XiK140CmAU2cryzBAA)
It's up to you to accurately define the parasitics and cable impedance, then choose match source R values and consider some load R...